# "Incomplete Type" when open hashing c++

Tags: c++11, recursion, hash, hashtable, backtracking

Im new to C++ and I'm getting an error which I've never seen before.  I am attempting to search by a backtracking algorithm that uses a hash table (open hashing).

Before I make a recursive call, I'm searching the hash table to see if the current position has been searched before (and has failed) and then inserting vector of ints "B" into the hash table when the recursive call returns false so that future search for the same position can be avoided.

Heres my function in my program calling file to hash:

```
bool open_hash_solve (vector<int> B, vector<Move> & MS, vector<Move> & TMS, OpenHashTable<vector<int>> & H) {

  if (solved(B))
    return true;

  vector<Move> curr = currentMoves(B, TMS);

  for (int m = 0; m < curr.size(); m++) {

    vector<int> moveMade = makeMove(B, curr[m]);

    if (!H.contains(moveMade)){

      if (open_hash_solve(moveMade, MS, TMS, H)){

        MS.insert(MS.begin(), curr[m]);
        return true;
      }
      else
        H.insert(moveMade);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Header file Separate Chaining from the textbook:

```
#ifndef SEPARATE_CHAINING_H
#define SEPARATE_CHAINING_H

#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;


int nextPrime( int n );

// SeparateChaining Hash table class
//
// CONSTRUCTION: an approximate initial size or default of 101
//
// ******************PUBLIC OPERATIONS*********************
// bool insert( x )       --> Insert x
// bool remove( x )       --> Remove x
// bool contains( x )     --> Return true if x is present
// void makeEmpty( )      --> Remove all items

template <typename HashedObj>
class OpenHashTable
{
 public:
  explicit OpenHashTable( int size = 101 ) : currentSize{ 0 }
  { theLists.resize( 101 ); }

  bool contains( const HashedObj & x ) const
  {
    auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( x ) ];
    return find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), x ) != end( whichList );
  }

  void makeEmpty( )
  {
    for( auto & thisList : theLists )
      thisList.clear( );
  }

  bool insert( const HashedObj & x )
  {
    auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( x ) ];
    if( find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), x ) != end( whichList) )
      return false;
    whichList.push_back( x );

    // Rehash; see Section 5.5
    if( ++currentSize > theLists.size( ) )
      rehash( );

    return true;
  } 

  bool insert( HashedObj && x )
  {
    auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( x ) ];
    if( find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), x ) != end( whichList ) )
      return false;
    whichList.push_back( std::move( x ) );

    // Rehash; see Section 5.5
    if( ++currentSize > theLists.size( ) )
      rehash( );

    return true;
  }

  bool remove( const HashedObj & x )
  {
    auto & whichList = theLists[ myhash( x ) ];
    auto itr = find( begin( whichList ), end( whichList ), x );

    if( itr == end( whichList ) )
      return false;

    whichList.erase( itr );
    --currentSize;
    return true;
  }

 private:
  vector<list<HashedObj>> theLists;   // The array of Lists
  int  currentSize;

  void rehash( )
  {
    vector<list<HashedObj>> oldLists = theLists;

    // Create new double-sized, empty table
    theLists.resize( nextPrime( 2 * theLists.size( ) ) );
    for( auto & thisList : theLists )
      thisList.clear( );

    theLists.resize( nextPrime( 2 * theLists.size( ) ) );
    for( auto & thisList : theLists )
      thisList.clear( );

    // Copy table over
    currentSize = 0;
    for( auto & thisList : oldLists )
      for( auto & x : thisList )
        insert( std::move( x ) );
  }

  size_t myhash( const HashedObj & x ) const
  {
    static hash<HashedObj> hf;  ***** ERROR HERE *****
    return hf( x ) % theLists.size( );
  }
};

#endif
```

My Error:

```
SeparateChaining.h: In instantiation of ‘size_t OpenHashTable<HashedObj>::myhash(const HashedObj&) const [with HashedObj = std::vector<int>; size_t = long unsigned int]’:

SeparateChaining.h:33:44:   required from ‘bool OpenHashTable<HashedObj>::contains(const HashedObj&) const [with HashedObj = std::vector<int>]’

movetest1.cpp:107:29:   required from here

SeparateChaining.h:106:34: error: ‘std::hash<std::vector<int> > hf’ has incomplete type
 static hash<HashedObj> hf;
                        ^
```

How do I fix this??
Let me know if my description doesn't make sense or needs clarity. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you put the line invoking the compiler (with all parameters)? If you can also tell the compiler version ...

Comment: g++ -g -std=c++11 movetest1.cpp @lrleon

Comment: Apparently, the compiler does not know the type hash<HashedObj>. I guess that's the hash function, which supposedly should return a value of type size_t. But the type is hash<HashedObj> and not size_t.

The next line is also strange because it performs module (%), which requires that the type hash<HashedObj> can be converted to an integer. That is the case?

Verify that the compiler has knowledge of that type (hash<T>)

Comment: I believe the type hash<HashedObj> is converted into an integer @lrleon

Comment: I modified myhash to this:                                     int myhash( const HashedObj & x ) const
  {
    int hashVal = hash( x ) ;

    hashVal %= theLists.size( );
    if( hashVal < 0 )
      hashVal += theLists.size( );

    return hashVal;                                              Now I get the error:                                     SeparateChaining.h: In member function ‘int OpenHashTable<HashedObj>::myhash(const HashedObj&) const’:
SeparateChaining.h:111:23: error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
     int hashVal = hash( x ) ;
@lrleon

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `std::hash` is not defined for `std::vector` except `std::vector<bool>`. It's defined only for [basic types and select library types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash). You have to implement your own hashing algorithm.

Regarding your last comment, `hash( x )` is invalid code since `std::hash` is a class template, not a function template.

You also can't write your own specialization for `std::hash<std::vector<int>>` since `std::vector<int>` is not a user-defined type.

Appropriate solution would be in the style of [C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) - `OpenHashTable` should allow its user to specify hashing algorithm:

```
template<typename HashedObj, typename Hash = std::hash<HashedObj>>
class OpenHashTable {
    // ...
    size_t myhash(const HashedObj& x) const {
        static Hash hf;
        return hf(x) % theLists.size();
    }
};
```

So you can use it as follows:

```
struct my_vector_int_hash {
    size_t operator()(const std::vector<int>& v) const {
        // your code here
    }
};

OpenHashTable<std::vector<int>, my_vector_int_hash> hashtable;
```

---

Update: as long as discussion arose about whether you can specialize `std::hash<std::vector<int>>`, here is why you are not allowed to do it.

`[namespace.std]/1` says:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace `std` only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

`std::vector<int>` is not a user-defined type, nor it depends on any user-defined type, so such specialization is illegal and leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: As explained below, you can specialize hash<std::vector<int >>. It may not be as elegant, but you can. I've checked @Savin

Comment: @lrleon it's undefined behavior.

Comment: so like this?  template<typename HashedObj, typename Hash = std::hash<HashedObj>>  
class OpenHashTable {       ...                                     int myhash( const HashedObj & x ) const    
  {    
    int hashVal = hash( x ) ;  

    hashVal %= theLists.size( );  
    if( hashVal < 0 )  
      hashVal += theLists.size( );  

    return hashVal;  
  }  
 Hash m_hash;  
};

Comment: Im not quite understanding your answer

Comment: @dave1234 I added implementation of `myhash` how it should be

Comment: I am given the same error with your code:                       In instantiation of ‘size_t OpenHashTable<HashedObj, Hash>::myhash(const HashedObj&) const [with HashedObj = std::vector<int>; Hash = std::hash<std::vector<int> >; size_t = long unsigned int]’:
SeparateChaining.h:34:44:   required from ‘bool OpenHashTable<HashedObj, Hash>::contains(const HashedObj&) const [with HashedObj = std::vector<int>; Hash = std::hash<std::vector<int> >]’
movetest1.cpp:107:29:   required from here
SeparateChaining.h:110:16: error: ‘std::hash<std::vector<int> > hf’ has incomplete type
    static Hash hf;

Comment: @dave1234 you have to implement your own hash. That's the whole point.

Comment: @dave1234 sorry if it wasn't clear. I updated my answer with a clarification and a stub custom hash function code.

Comment: @dave1234 as "workaround", you can define your own type. For example, `struct MyMove : public vector<int> { ...};`. Thus you has your own type and you would conform the rules. You could use `using MyMove = vector<int>`, but I suspect that this will annoy to Anton. And you can do exactly as I said you and that will work ... on the understanding that is a workaround (in this sense Anton comments are right)